# How to make a InkWell/GestureDetector clickable when they are overflowing parent?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stack inside a Container with fixed size. The Stack has Positioned children with InkWell children inside. If I push a child to the left with e.g. left: -15, the InkWell is still visible outside the Container, however not clickable anymore outside of the Container.

Here the simplified version of the code:

```dart
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
  child: Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: -15,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text("Test"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I am trying to make the overflowing part (the 15 pixels to the left) of the InkWell clickable too. Right now I can only click everything inside the container.

The reason I am doing this is to make buttons easier clickable, while not moving the visible text to a different location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly:

> It is intentional that widgets in the overflow area of a stack do not react to gestures and that's unlikely to change. I recommend that people with this (or similar) problems refactor their app to keep all interactable elements within the bounds of a stack.
>
> source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445

In short, don't use overflow. Refactor your layout to make sure it's well contained inside the bounds of its parent.