# Flutter InkWell on tap is not being detected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using inkwell to detect tap. I also use gesturedetector but that didn't work as well. Found a solution that say wrap the child with IgnorePointer, but that didn't work as well.

Here is my code:

```
Positioned(
                            bottom: -67,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Tap');
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 70,
                                height: 70,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    width: 5,
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color:
                                          Color(0xFF000000).withAlpha(11),
                                      blurRadius: 16,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 24,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

This is the button on which i want to detect tap.

[image: The Button on which i want to detect tap]

**EDIT: It is detecting the tap but outside the white border of circle avatar. I want the whole White border and circle avatar to be clickable. Removing the positioned makes the whole container clickable but now how i want to position that element in the stack !!!**

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. The only thing I notice in your code is that only your inner onTap method will be triggered  since you wrap your InkWill with another InkWell

Comment: Try wrapping your Inkwell with Material.

Comment: Use other tap methods rather thann InkWell

Comment: @quoci I want it for both circle ... how to do that ?

Comment: @Venky like ? What others ?

Comment: Gesture Detector

Comment: @Venky have tried that didn't work.

Comment: @HanzalaSaeed Wrapping in InkWell doesn't benefit as well

Comment: One InkWell is enough. Why use another one inside?

Comment: @quoci I want whole widget ... the white border and also the circle avatar to detect on tap ... how to do that ?

Comment: @quoci I have tried another approach as well, like using icon button as shown in the edit ... but that is not working as well !!!

Comment: @quoci Now it is working but only for the white border not for the circle avatar !! :-( and even not the whole white border just outside that white circle !!!!

Comment: @quoci see the question edit

Comment: Did you try ```behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque``` for the GestureDetector?

Comment: @Arun yes didn't work sadly !!!

Comment: @Arun https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852963/9138027 this is the problem do you know any workaround for this ?

Comment: @AliYarKhan No, I unfortunately do not. Like mentioned in that answer, it would probably be best to redesign the widget such that it doesn't depend on overflow.

Comment: How to design such element? Can you please the design in the question and see if any solution other than over flow is available ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove Positioned widget and wrap the container in Inkwell

Comment: But I want to position the button at bottom: -65.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/57852963/9138027 this is the problem do you know any workaround for this